# Cast Column as Text or Prefix with Apostrophe When Writing a CSV File in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a script that that dumps data from a database into a CSV file via the Python CSV writer (more accurately, unicodecsv)

My problem is I have one column that I need to cast as text or prefix as an apostrophe because it's a 16 digit number and formats as scientific when viewed in Excel.  THe code works perfectly otherwise.    The column name is simply called "value".   Any clean ways to achieve this?

```
def dump(self, sql, filename, include_headers=True):
    f = unicodecsv.writer(file(filename + ".csv", 'wb'), dialect=unicodecsv.excel, quoting=unicodecsv.QUOTE_ALL)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.connect_string)
c = cnxn.cursor()
c.execute(sql)

if include_headers:
    f.writerow([d[0] for d in c.description])

    for row in c.fetchall():
        f.writerow(row)

   # f.close()
    cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Can you construct a query that will return that column as a string from the db?

Comment: Or, iterate over the rows and replace the offending values: [https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Rows.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Rows.wiki)

Comment: I went with your suggestion and prefixed the SQL code with an apostrophe and it works... sort of.   The apostrophe shows up in Excel instead of simply formatting the cell like usual, which I can live with.   I would prefer to do this at the Python level, but it works.

Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the rows and replace the value with a string:

First example: define a function that makes a change then use `map` to implement the change:

```
import functools
def change(row, col):
    '''changes the column of a pyodbc row

    returns modified pyodbc row
    '''
    return setattr(row, col, str(getattr(row, col)))

# partial function that specifies the 'foo' column
change_foo = functools.partial(change, col = 'foo')

if include_headers:
    f.writerow([d[0] for d in c.description])
    rows = c.fetchall()
    # modify the column in each row
    rows = map(change_foo, rows)
    for row in rows:
        f.writerow(row)
```

---

Second example: just modify the column before writing it

```
if include_headers:
    f.writerow([d[0] for d in c.description])
    for row in = c.fetchall():
        row.foo = str(row.foo)
        f.writerow(row)
```

---

Or even:

```
if include_headers:
    f.writerow([d[0] for d in c.description])
    for row in = c.fetchall():
        f.writerow(change_foo(row))
```

Comment: I played around with this and got the ideal results.  HUGE thank you!